# How do I use antialiasing programmatically in OpenGl ES Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, antialiasing

So the title pretty much says it already, I use the OpenGl ES template in Xcode to create a game. I use triangles for my code.

So what I want is basically the same like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928181/antialiasing-on-opengl-es-2-0), just for iOS instead of Android.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Read Microsoft document about AA http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/overdraw.pdf

Comment: @ValarMorghulis well this explains the way it works but does not tell me how to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813035/opengl-es-iphone-drawing-anti-aliased-lines look at this. I hope will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While initializing the `GLKView`, call this to enable 4x MSAA, with `view` being your `GLKView` instance:

```
[view setDrawableMultisample: GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X];
```

Comment: Great! But it really tears down the fps in large files, is there a way to prevent the frame drop?

Comment: How much is the performance loss in your case? It really shouldn't be that much, particularly on newer GPUs.

Comment: So on a huge file (1,9000,000 objects in array, while 6 objects are 1 point) it is 15fps with aa. But I just double-checked, without it it is 16fps. So this is apparently not the problem. Probably just the size

Comment: oh and one more thing, do you know a way to increase the aa?